# jCarousel not working properly within tabbed menu

Tags: jcarousel, image-gallery, tabbed

I'm riding three different jCarousel ul, one in each target of a tabbed menu designeb by Yetii. The problem issue is that the one in the first target works well, whereas the remaining two show just a slice of the first picture and slide soon onto a back frame.

The jCarousel is initialized by a class as the behaviour required is the same for all targets:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('.jcarousel-skin-tango').jcarousel({
wrap: 'circular',
//size:8,
scroll:1,
animation:.10,
auto:5,
     });
});
```

The ul have different id. Tried also initializing the script by separate id but nothing changed.

Any suggestion on it? Thanks in advance - Mauirizio

Comment: Did you assign unique id's to your elements?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the second and third tab is display: none while your page loading!
Note that Jcarousel need to calculate the width and height of `ul`, therefore fails to do so.
you need to use different method for your tabs panes as:

```
position: absolute;
left: -10000px;
```

This may be a substitute for your `"display: none"` property.